# Python: Building dictionaries from csv

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to automate some boring monkey jobs for fortigate firewalls. I receive requests to create address objects for example for 100 different hosts.. many of which should belong to same address group.
My csv is

```
name,address,group
aix01,10.0.0.1,AIXGROUP1
aix02,10.0.0.2,AIXGROUP1
aix02,10.0.0.3,AIXGROUP2
aix245,10.0.0.4,AIXGROUP2
```

As you see above, there are 2x groups with 2x hosts in each.
I want to take the group names "AIXGROUP1" and "AIXGROUP2" as a dictionary keys and take list of each of the respective IPs as it's values.
So, it should be {AIXGROUP1:[10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2], AIXGROUP2:[10.0.0.3,10.0.0.4]}
I would then pass this dictionary to a function that prints the commands.
Here's the code

```
with open('hosts.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    Dictionary = {}
    for each in reader:
       if len(each[2])!=0:
          Dictionary[each[2]] = []
```

at this point I just have a dictionary with correct keys and empty lists as values.. and here's where I'm stuck.. how do I populate these empty lists with ip addresses?
I feel like I'm inch away from the victory! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop needs to take different actions depending on whether the group name is already in the dictionary or not, like this (I'll use `d` instead of `Dictionary` for brevity):

```
group = each[2]
ip = each[1]
if group in d:
    d[group].append(ip)  # Append another IP to the list
else:
    d[group] = [ip]  # Initialize list with first element
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to a solution. The only thing you need to add is a check if the key already exist in the dictionary, so you don't overwrite it and then add a row that adds the value to the list. And you can add the row `next(reader, None)` if you don't want the header row in the dictionary. Something like this should work:

```
with open('hosts.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader, None)  # To skip the header row
    Dictionary = {}
    for each in reader:
        if len(each[2])!=0 and each[2] not in Dictionary.keys(): # To not overwrite keys that already exist
            Dictionary[each[2]] = []
        Dictionary[each[2]].append(each[1]) #To add the values
```

Comment: I told you I was inch away from victory :)
Many thanks Sefan :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
result = {}
for row in reader:
    if len(row[2])!=0:
        try:
            result[row[2]].append(row[1]) 
        except:
            result[row[2]] = [row[1]]
result
>>> {'AIXGROUP1': ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2'], 'AIXGROUP2': ['10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.4']}
```

This approach creates the lists and fills them in the same loop. The `try / except` logic is faster than a conditional and works like this:

1. For each row of data, try to append the address to the right group.
2. If the exception is raised, that key doesn't yet exist in the dictionary, so we have to create it.
3. On creating the key, we define the key as a list with one element in it, which is the current address.
4. If the exception isn't raised, the dictionary already has one address for that key, so we just append the next one to the list referenced by that key.

Note that it's probably not best practice to name your output `dict` Dictionary. Also, if you are going to use `csv.read()`, don't forget to skip the header row!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv

# create the dictionary in which your data will be stored
ip_dict = {}

# open the wanted file
with open('hosts.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    # read the csv data
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # skip the header
    next(csv_reader)
    # parse your data
    for _, ip, name in csv_reader:
        # do whatever you need only if name is not empty
        if name:
            # if there is already an entry in the dictionary then append to it
            if name in ip_dict:
                ip_dict[name].append(ip)
            # if there is not create a list with the current ip as the first entry
            else:
                ip_dict[name] = [ip]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think my final version will be this.

```
def parser():
    Address_Groups = {}
    Addresses = {}
    with open ('Data.csv','r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            if row [0] not in Addresses:
                Addresses[row[0]] = row[1]
            if row[2] not in Address_Groups:
                Address_Groups[row[2]] = []
            if row[2] in row:   
                Address_Groups[f'{row[2]}'].append(f'{row[0]}')
    return (Addresses,Address_Groups)
```

Like this I successfully map some server name to it's respective IP address and name to respective address group.

when I do `return (Objects,Address_Groups)`it returns  a tuple of two dictionaries, right?
so if I do `print(parser())`
What I'm getting is a tuple(?) of two dictionaries.. is that right?

```
({'Host-01': '192.168.1.1', 'Host-02': '192.168.1.2', 'Host-03': '192.168.1.3', 'Host-04': '192.168.1.4'}, {'Test_Group-01': ['Host-01', 'Host-02'], 'Test_Group-02': ['Host-03'], 'Test_Group-012': ['Host-04']})
```

Comment: The question was how to create a dictionary, not a tuple.
The problem can be solved with the defaultdict from the collections python library.
See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My objective is to parse the csv data. I want to receive dictionary that maps Hostnames (fortigate address objects) to address group names. so with this function I return two dictionaries.. I later access these dictionaries by tuple index.
the code generates dictionaries.. it just returns them in tuple, thats the difference. The fundamental objective to build dictionary out of csv data is achieved anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the **collections** python library. It was created exactly for your case.

```
ar = [
'aix01,10.0.0.1,AIXGROUP1',
'aix02,10.0.0.2,AIXGROUP1',
'aix02,10.0.0.3,AIXGROUP2',
'aix245,10.0.0.4,AIXGROUP2'    
]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for row in ar:
    elements = row.split(',')
    d[elements[2]].append(elements[1])
    
print(dict(d))
```

This will print

> {'AIXGROUP1': ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2'], 'AIXGROUP2': ['10.0.0.3',
> '10.0.0.4']}

Answer (score 0):

So.. to make it more clear I will explain this from A to Z

I'm a network engineer who works primarily with fortigate firewalls.
Sometimes I receive the requests to add lots of address objects on the firewall.
Often times these objects should belong to address groups and later I use these address objects and address groups in firewall policies.
My objective was to create a short script that would write the firewall CLI commands in the file

so initially I structured the csv file in this way. Script should go through this and write firewall commands into a text file.

```
name,address,group
aix01,10.0.0.1,AIXGROUP1
aix02,10.0.0.2,AIXGROUP1
aix03,10.0.0.3,AIXGROUP2
aix04,10.0.0.4,AIXGROUP2
```

firewall cli command for adding object

```
config firewall address
 edit <Address Object Name>
  set subnet <IP> <Mask>
  set comment <Comment>
 next
 end
```

and for adding hosts into address group

```
config firewall addrgrp
 edit <Address Group Name>
  set member "<Address Object>" "<Address Object>"
  set comment <comment>
 next
 end
```

For My initial question I used very simple csv and question was how to build the dictionary from the csv file specifically for the address group mapping because how I see this working is to have group name as a KEY and list of group members as VALUES. so in the initial example desired result was

```
{
AIXGROUP1:[aix01,aix02], 
AIXGROUP2:[aix03,aix04]
}
```

I was stuck at this part -  I was getting correct keys but was unable to populate the value lists with correct IP addresses/hostnames.
I had all the command printer functions ready, waiting for this dictionary as argument but these argument was never coming because I was unable to build the dictionary.
So, thank to all the replied codes that is written in this thread, the initial code was fixed and I got the dictionary I wanted.

After solving the initial issue, I moved a bit further and modified the csv by adding extra column "action". So, whenever my client requests existing address object to be added to some address group, I will leave the "action" empty but  if it's a new address object, it will have the action "add"..
Real life csv file looks very similar to this.. except it has much more data in it sometimes.

```
action,name,ip,group
,host01,192.168.0.1,Test01
,host02,192.168.0.2,Test01
add,host03,192.168.0.3,Test02
add,host04,192.168.0.4,Test02
add,host05,192.168.0.5,Test03
,host06,192.168.0.6,Test04
add,host07,192.168.0.7,Test04
add,host08,192.168.0.8,
add,host09,192.168.0.9,
```

Meaning:

1: host01 and host02 already exist on the firewall but needs to be added to Test01 group

2: host03 and host04 needs to be created AND added to Test02 group

3: host05 needs to be created AND added to Test03 group

4: host06 exists but needs to be added to Test04 group

5: host07 needs to be created AND added to Test04 group

6: host08 and host09 need to be just created.. without adding it to any group.

I updated the code accordingly so here is the final version that does exactly what I wanted (to get the dictionary and pass them to printer function)
Instead of one dictionary I now return tuple of two dictionaries and later on I pass that tuple indexes to command printer function.

first dictionary is for adding the address objects. In this dictionary keys are the address object names and values are it's respective IP addresses.. so,each key will have just one value - IP

Other dictionary is for groups where keys are the group names and values are the list of group members.

```
import csv
from ipaddress import IPv4Address,IPv4Network, ip_address, ip_network
from datetime import datetime
commands = open('commands.txt','w')
comment = f'"COMMENT-USERNAME-{datetime.now() :%b-%d-%Y}"'
''' 
This function goes through the csv file and returns two dictionaries. 
1: {Hostname:IP}
2: {Address_Groups:[list of hostnames]}
Later on we will use each of these dictionaries as Command_Printer function arguments. 
'''
def Parser():
    Address_Groups = {}
    Addresses = {}
    with open ('Data2.csv','r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            Action=row[0]
            Hostname=row[1]
            IP=row[2]
            GROUP=row[3]
            if 'add' in Action and Hostname not in Addresses:
                Addresses[Hostname] = IP
            if GROUP not in Address_Groups:
                Address_Groups[GROUP] = []
            if GROUP in row:    
                Address_Groups[f'{GROUP}'].append(f'"{Hostname}"')
    return (Addresses,Address_Groups)
"""
Command printer
"""
def Command_Printer(addr,addrgrp):
    for key,value in addr.items():
        IPcheck = IPv4Network(value, strict = False).with_netmask
        Address = IPcheck.split('/')
        commands.write(f'config firewall address\n')
        commands.write(f'edit {key}\n')
        commands.write(f'set subnet {Address[0]} {Address[1]}\n')
        commands.write(f'set comment {comment}\n')
        commands.write(f'next\n')
        commands.write(f'end\n \n')
    for key, value in addrgrp.items():
        if key != '':
            commands.write(f'config firewall addrgrp\n')
            commands.write(f'edit {key}\n')
            commands.write(f'set member {" ".join(value)}\n')
            commands.write(f'set comment {comment}\n')
            commands.write(f'next\n')
            commands.write(f'end\n \n')
"""Go babe! Go!"""
def Main():
    Call = Parser()
    addr = Call[0]
    addrgrp=Call[1]
    Command_Printer(addr,addrgrp)
Main()
commands.close
```

Result is this:

```
config firewall address
 edit host03
  set subnet 192.168.0.3 255.255.255.255
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
end

config firewall address
 edit host04
  set subnet 192.168.0.4 255.255.255.255
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
end
config firewall address
 edit host05
  set subnet 192.168.0.5 255.255.255.255
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
end
config firewall address
 edit host07
  set subnet 192.168.0.7 255.255.255.255
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
end
config firewall address
 edit host08
  set subnet 192.168.0.8 255.255.255.255
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
 end
config firewall address
 edit host09
  set subnet 192.168.0.9 255.255.255.255
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
 end
config firewall addrgrp
 edit Test01
  set member "host01" "host02"
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
 end
config firewall addrgrp
 edit Test02
  set member "host03" "host04"
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
 end
config firewall addrgrp
 edit Test03
  set member "host05"
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
 end
config firewall addrgrp
 edit Test04
  set member "host06" "host07"
  set comment "COMMENT-USERNAME-Nov-06-2021"
  next
 end
```

Later on I'm planning to add the policies and maybe VPN tunnels too but for that I think I will need to come up with some class and use pandas instead of csv module. but that's a topic for another day.
If you find this useful, please feel free to use, update, etc the way you want. no limits whatsoever. There is probably million other ways to do this task.

p.s

Apart from all the "banana" and "apple" code examples I've gone through, this is my very first working script that actually has some real life use for me and  it feels great and I'm happy I learned allot thank to code examples all of you provided.
Thanks for all the help and for your time to read all this <3